# how to use Qt Creator source code in my project to create a file management system like Qt's project

Tags: c++, qt

In my recent project,i need to accomplish a file management system like Qt Creator's "Projects part" in the left-top .I tried to use QTreeView to implement it,but it's effect is far less than my expention.Since Qt Creator's source code is open,can i use it's code and make some needed change? And can you tell me which files to refer to ? I am using Qt4 in my project.
[this picture shows want i mean "projects part"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NACz5.jpg)

Comment: First make sure you do not violate the licence on the Qt Creator sources, it is open, but still licensed. Second have a look at the [Qtilities](http://jpnaude.github.io/Qtilities/) libraries. The [Building Trees](http://jpnaude.github.io/Qtilities/page_tree_structures.html) page might be a good start.

Comment: Qt creator uses the same widgets as well. Post a new question / update this with what have you done so far and what errors you are getting.